# Making a win-lose record query in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

Sorry in advance if I make some grammatical mistakes. The thing is that I'm making a MMA database with tables such as "Fighters" and "Fights".

In the table "Fights" I have two fields: WINNER and LOSER, so, in order to see how many fights are won or lose by a fighter I made two queries: one counting the wins and another one counting the losses. But I feel that is kinda useless.

Queries in SQL view:

```
SELECT FIGHTS.WINNER, Count(FIGHTS.WINNER) AS WIN
FROM FIGHTS
GROUP BY FIGHTS.WINNER;
___

SELECT FIGHTS.LOSER, Count(FIGHTS.LOSER) AS LOSE
FROM FIGHTS
GROUP BY FIGHTS.LOSER;
```

Resulting:

```
WINNER              WINS
Raquel Pennington   1
Sara McMann         1
Sarah D'Alelio      2
Sarah Maloy         1
____

LOSER               LOSE
Kaitlin Young       2
Lacey Schuckman     1
Lisa Ellis          1
Meghan Wright       1
```

I'd like a query that shows the losers and vice versa, so it could be something like this:

```
WINNER              WINS
Raquel Pennington   1
Sara McMann         1
Sarah D'Alelio      2
Sarah Maloy         1
Kaitlin Young       0
Lacey Schuckman     0
Lisa Ellis          0
Meghan Wright       0
___
LOSER               LOSE
Kaitlin Young       2
Lacey Schuckman     1
Lisa Ellis          1
Meghan Wright       1
Raquel Pennington   0
Sara McMann         0
Sarah D'Alelio      0
Sarah Maloy         0
```

I tried a lot of different combinations, queries, but it always ended messed up with names duplicated, incorrect records...
If I get to make this queries then the rest is piece of cake. I feel that I'm halfway there, but I'm totally blocked.

If you need screenshots or more info just ask, english is not my first language and it's hard to explain myself. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using two tables - `Fights` and `Fighters`:

[image]

This query will return the total Wins/Losses:

```
SELECT  Fighter
        , COUNT(F1.WINNER) AS Wins
        , COUNT(F2.LOSER) AS Losses
FROM    (Fighters LEFT JOIN Fights F1 ON Fighters.Fighter = F1.Winner)
                  LEFT JOIN Fights F2 ON Fighters.Fighter = F2.Loser
GROUP   BY Fighter
```

Giving this result:
[image]

In design view the query would look like this:
(**Note**: I haven't aliased the table names or result fields so the resulting query will have `CountOfWINNER` and `CountOfLoser` as field names).
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought it was going to be more complex. I wonder if the only way to make this is by SQL or it can be done with the the design view?

Comment: Yes, it can be done in design view - there's no joins between the tables that can't be shown in design view, you just have to add the Fights table twice (I've updated my answer to show the design view).  Also note - I've made both fields in Fights part of the primary key, so no chance of rematches. :)

Comment: Thank you again, you've been tremendously helpful ;)